# ASP.NET / Windows Service design

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-services, webserver

I thought begin to touch the goal, but hey I can not find a complete solution.
Thank you in advance to those who take the time to read and respond.

I need to develop an ASP.NET site to the management of the company : projects, resources , planning ....
So I thought a MVC 4 project ( thank you Express Editions )
Except that my first problem happened , we can not do background tasks directly in ASP.NET.

With a response on a forum PhP who told me Cron Tasks I finally found that I should make a windows service that would handle tasks funds related to ASP.NET server with a web service . I was then talking about Web CallBack Service (WCF) .

Yet with all this, I still can not make a pattern relatively common in this type of application : the real-time notification .

Suppose a user wants to generate a notification or the windows service automatically generates , how I could notify all users connected to the ASP.NET server?

Then, I want a ASP.NET site architecture or have a connection with the management of windows service wholesale.
How would you personally?

Thank you in advance

Good day

Answer (score 0):

Up

Nobody have do something like that? =s
I don't say that real time, windows service and web service are good idea. 
That's just i have found.

Good Day

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `SignalR`. There is a good *[article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1146/building-a-shopping-cart-with-signalr-aspnet-web-api-and-knockoutjs)* on *tech.pro*

---

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/647155/Creating-Real-Time-System-Notifications-with-Signa
2. http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2013/03/07/Real-time-User-Notification-and-Session-Management-with-SignalR-Part-1.aspx